# Dividing IP range into chunk of 1024 using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a *starting IP address* and *count of IP*. I want to break the count into chunk of 1024 and produce a list in following manner:

**Sample Input**

```
ip = 90.1.0.0
count = 12000
```

**Desired Output** (Column #1 denotes starting IP and column #2 denotes count)

```
90.1.0.0 1024
90.1.4.0 1024
90.1.8.0 1024
90.1.12.0 1024
90.1.16.0 1024
90.1.20.0 1024
90.1.24.0 1024
90.1.28.0 1024
90.1.32.0 1024
90.1.36.0 1024
90.1.40.0 1024
90.1.44.0 736
```

**Short description**

- There will be 1024 ips in between range `90.1.0.0` to `90.1.4.0` (total count = `1024 * 1 = 1024`)
- There will be 1024 ips in between range `90.1.4.0` to `90.1.8.0` (total count = `1024 * 2 = 2048`), like wise
- There will be 1024 ips in between range `90.1.36.0` to `90.1.40.0` (total count = `1024 * 11 = 11264`
- Since we need count 12000, (`12000 - 11264 = 736`) will be needed in last ip range which will be `90.1.40.0 to 90.1.44.0`

**Other sample**

input :

```
ip = 90.1.0.0
count = 32
```

output :

```
90.1.0.0 32
```

Can you please suggest how to proceed with this? I am new to Stack Overflow, so please guide me if I missed something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
def from_string(s):
    "Convert dotted IPv4 address to integer."
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a<<8 | b, map(int, s.split(".")))

def to_string(ip):
    "Convert 32-bit integer to dotted IPv4 address."
    return ".".join(map(lambda n: str(ip>>n & 0xFF), [24,16,8,0]))

ip = '90.1.0.0'
count = 12000
block_size = 1024

ip_int = from_string(ip)
while count > 0:
    delta = min(count, block_size)
    print to_string(ip_int), delta
    ip_int += delta
    count -= delta
```

IP converison code taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/cslarsen/1595135).

Answer (score 2):

`python3` comes with a library `ipaddress` (for python2 there's a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress)) that makes it really easy to work with ip addresses.

In your case, you could write a generator producing the result you want like this:

```
import ipaddress

def addresses(start, count, interval):
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(start)
    while count > 0:
            yield addr, min(count, interval)
            count -= interval
            addr += interval

for addr, num in addresses(u'90.1.0.0', 12000, 1024):
    print(addr, num)
```

Comment: I have python2.5, unable to install the module ipaddress (from backport link) because of version mismatch. Can you please let me know if it is available for python2.5?

Comment: I tried the code above with [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress) backport on python2.5, and it seems to work (although python2.5 isn't officially supported).

Comment: I am getting following error -> $python ip_ad.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_ad.py", line 1, in ?
    import ipaddress
ImportError: No module named ipaddress

Comment: @npatel: That means you haven't actually installed it, or you've installed it for a different Python installation than the one you're running. Without telling us how you installed it (as in the exact command lines or links to the exact binary installers you used), what platform you're on, what Python installations you have, how you start python, and (if you're not using an absolute path) what your `PATH` env variable is, it's pretty hard for anyone to debug things further.

Answer (score 0):

from_string function can also be written as follow:

```
def from_string(s):
    return int('0x'+''.join(['%02x'%int(x) for x in s.split('.')]), 16)
```

and to_string function:

```
import re
def to_string(ip):
    return '.'.join([str(int('0x'+x, 16)) for x in re.findall(r'(.{2})', str(hex(ip))[2:])])
```

NOTE: These calculations are for IPv4 only